# Why won't backgroundColor work (React Native)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How come `backgroundColor` won't change my entire phone screens background color?  All I'm getting is a blank white screen whenever I run my code.

Here's my `index.ios.js` file:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, View} from 'react-native';
import Login from './ios/components/login/Login';

export default class Epsilon extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
           <View>
               <Login/>
           </View>
        );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Epsilon', () => Epsilon);
```

Here's my `Login.js` file:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';

export default class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>

            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   container: {
       flex: 1,
       backgroundColor: '#3498db'
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it like this, Your flex is being ignored in the child component.So by adding flex to root u can fix this/

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, View} from 'react-native';
import Login from './ios/components/login/Login';

export default class Epsilon extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
           <View style={{flex:1}}>
               <Login/>
           </View>
        );
    }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Epsilon', () => Epsilon);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `flex: 1` is being ignored because the parent view has not set it's flex rules. You can either remove the wrapping top level view (if you are definitely only having one component in `Epsilon`), or add flex rules onto the wrapping view.